# curl - looking to test some Rest APIs - what is the syntax to Post xml to a rest api with basic authentication?

Tags: api, rest, curl, restful-authentication

curl - looking to test some Rest APIs - what is the syntax to Post xml to a rest api with basic authentication?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
curl -i POST -u "user:password" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d "<Foo></Foo>" http://example.org/resource
```

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Comment: What if it is an HTTPS url? Is there a way to trust certificates?

Comment: @moorecats the --cert option allows you to do that.

Comment: I exported a certificate from a url i was trying to hit and put that path in the command in this way - curl https://url.com --cert c:\cert.cer and I got this error now - curl: (58) unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?) 

My knowledge of certificates are limited, I know I do not need to put in a passphrase when hitting the site via Chrome/Firefox etc, so what is it looking for?